Trying to figure out how to create a continously updating filtered and sorted list based on a table that gets manually updated everyday
So I have come across a problem at work at the moment, and I can only really use the online version of Excel to do it (needs to be the online one for wider accessibility of the file, thought about using Power Query to do it and upload it onto a OneDrive file but I'm worried it may stop working once I leave the company and Im wanting to make it usable even after Im gone).
It is a pretty simple dataset. Only has about 8 columns, the important ones being the Customers Name, ID, Date of entry and a column that has a bolean input of only yes and no. It's basically a lead list that gets pre-vetted first before it goes to the sales team. The vetting team will put a yes or no on one of the columns to indicate whether the lead is worth a try or not. I need to create a seperate table on another sheet within the same workbook that only has the rows of data where the deciding column has a yes in it. It also needs to be sorted from most recent entry at the top of the list, and the oldest entry being on the bottom.
I was kind of able to make something using the INDIRECT and FILTER function, but I couldnt add SORT into this code and get it to work. Another problem I have is I need to add an extra column in the pasted sheet so that the different sales people can allocate the leads to their name. Which is another problem as the only solutions I've kind of found wouldnt work as the column with the sales people doesnt update with the list - meaning that the lead may have been taken already, but the data update causes there to be an extra column in the middle of the table so all the data gets pushed down one, misaligning the salesperson to the lead theyve taken.
I dont know how well I explained my problem, but if anyone could help me. That would be awesome!
I tried an =FILTER(INDIRECT("Main_List"), '$0 Wallet'!K2:K2000 = "Yay", "")
Main_List being the table with the data, and having to reference the specific column and sheet for the filter criteria. Works great, but the problem comes when any new data is supposed to be appended to the top and the salespersons name in the extra column doesnt follow with the data
It ends up looking like this -
Table before update



ID
SalesPerson




1234
Amanda


3421
Samuel



After data update



ID
SalesPerson




5556
Amanda


1234
Samuel


3421




Tables moved down, but the salesperson's name doesnt follow

Which table is your input and which one desired output?

Salesperson assignment needs to be either in the main table or a separate table. Are these assignments done concurrently by multiple persons?

Is column K in you filter part of Main_List?

Help me understand how the INDIRECT function comes into play here.  Why doesn't FILTER(Main_List,xxx) work?

The second part of your problem is going to be really hard to solve in Excel.  Mixing manual entry data in one column and logic-generated data in other columns sort of violates the "prime directive" (Star Trek reference) of how spreadsheets work.  That kind of "dynamic sign-up sheet" isn't well suited to Excel.  The act of the salesperson "signing up" for a lead is a transaction and a spreadsheet requires added logic (like VBA, for instance) to be transactional.

If it's "a pretty simple dataset", then it should be pretty simple to provide some (suitably anonymised) sample data?  Demonstrations/examples can help to make your problems clearer

The first part of your question isn't too complicated.  The second part is not, unfortunately, something that Excel is designed to do without the likes of VBA.  (In fact, it's almost exactly what Excel is specifically designed not to be able to do, because it tries to create Circular References.  Really, it sounds like you would be better off using MS Access, to build a Database with a suitable Form)
So, I'm going to ignore the second part, citing the "Questions should contain only one Problem" rule (a.k.a. "Needs More Focus"), and just answer the first part.

You are trying to SORT your list, and FILTER it, in a single action.  This means that you need to either FILTER your SORT results, or SORT your FILTER results, (with or without using SORTBY instead of SORT) which could look something like this:
=SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$A:$H, Sheet1!$H:$H="Y"), 7, -1)

(This assumes that the last column — column H — is your "Y/N" column, and the seventh column — column G — is your Date column)
This, however, will not copy across your headers, and looks at the entire column (rather than a more Dynamically sized range)
For dynamically sizing the range, use the fact that INDEX results can be treated as a regular cell reference, allowing you to combine them with :s.  Depending on your version of Excel, we can also use the LET function to reduce potential duplication, and make things easier to adjust in future.
For adding the Header back in, we can use the fact that INDEX with an empty argument can return the entire Row/Column, and the VSTACK function to combine tables of data.
=LET(dataRange, Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$H:$H, COUNTA(Sheet1!$H:$H)), 
     filterColumn, 8, 
     filterCriteria, "Y", 
     sortColumn, 7, 
     sortOrder, -1, 
     _FilteredData, FILTER(dataRange, INDEX(dataRange, filterColumn,)=filterCriteria), 
     _SortedData, SORT(_filteredData, sortColumn, sortOrder), 
     VSTACK(INDEX(dataRange,1,), _SortedData)
)

This will do much the same thing, but uses the number of values in Column H to control the range of data it looks at, and can be expanded to include other sorts/filters/data processing as required.
(If you want to change which is your "key column" — i.e. a column that will always contain data, and control how many rows are in the range — that's the column H in the COUNTA(Sheet1!$H:$H) bit)
